# Calculus: Calculate the electric charge that passes in 2 secods when a current of i=2sin(π/2)t flows

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

This question is on my integral work.

These are the steps I have gone through;

i = 2sin (π/2)t

Sin (π/2) = 1.

= 2 x 1t

= 2t

∫ 2/2t^2

=t^2

Where do I go from here. Substitute t with the time in question (2), then put that answer in the original equation?

Comment: Do you mean $2t \sin\frac{\pi}2$ or $2\sin\frac{t\pi}2$? Also, I don't understand what you are doing at lines 2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: The exact equation which is written down is is i=2sin(π/2)t

Comment: I'd like to know if the sine is affected by the value of t, it is unclear from what you have written. Please, pick one of these terms or use MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $i = 2sin(\frac{π}{2})t$ Thats literally how it's written. The t is actually outside of the brackets. If you integrate this I end up with t^2

Comment: Well then, I thought that the assignment can't be such easy.

Comment: Since $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1$, I suspect what was intended was $i = 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} t\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the current starts at $t=0$ and the units are seconds. It's not explicitly written in your assingment but it is important.
I don't know if I read the integral correctly. There should be:

$$\int_0^22t = [t^2]_0^2 = 2^2-0^2=4$$

Comment: That makes complete sense. I was struggling because I didn't recognise that the lower limit was 0, but yeah this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general, the relation between charge and current can be described as
$$i(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}Q(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
So if you want to compute the charge at a certain time, you would do something like
$$Q(t) = \int_{0}^{t}i(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$$
From a physical perspective, both quantities need a multiplicative constant that is assigning a unit to the respective quantity. That should look like $\hat{\mathrm{I}}$ for the current and $\hat{\mathrm{Q}}$ for the charge. I mention this because by following your approach, you would assign a value of time in seconds $[s]$ to electrical charge which is measured in Coulombs $[C]$.